# Did labelled loops pre-date for loops?

Tags: history, loops, control-structures

Was the first implementation of looping control flow effectively the `goto`  (or something like a labelled `JMP` in assembler) or was there another syntactic construction?

`for` (`für`) was introduced in Superplan in 1949 IIRC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if your question title matches the actual question, as jump instructions in assembler may be relative, i.e. unlabelled as well. I'm also no historian, but I can at least subtract another century from your estimate.

The [Analytical Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_Engine#Instruction_set) devised by Charles Baggage in 1837 was extended in 1845 to contain a conditional jump instruction similar to modern assembler jump operations. See the linked wikipedia entry for an example code.

While that sets back the first implementation of such a control structure by a good century, I cannot say whether earlier versions exist. Most probably you may need to refine your question, as I believe there exists earlier work on the theoretical concept and it's hard to decide whether anything before the analytical engine is an *implementation* depending on your definition of it.

Answer (score -2):

Assembler has several low-level jump operations including a non-conditional jump to a label and several conditional jumps to a label.  The conditional jumps execute only if a specific control flag condition is true, otherwise program flow drops through to the next instruction.  There is also a loop instruction that affects the value in the ecx register and jumps to a label when non-zero.

Comment: He said this already in his question.